# Will Xamarin carry its runtime for all its apps?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am wondering Xamarin carries Mono runtime with its all app package. In this case, if two Xamarin based app installed in a device which will be having two Mono runtime right. Is it a limitation with Xamarin?

Answer (score 5):

On iOS each app has its copy of the runtime.  iOS does not allow for sharing of between apps.

On Android you have the ability to select whether or not to use a shared runtime, but this is generally recommended only for debugging, not production.

Comment: As a side note: Usage of a shared runtime on Android via the Google Play Store has only ever been granted to Adobe's AIR runtime. Of course this does not matter if you control the install base via ad-hoc /enterprise deployments...